# Encrypted API call via JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am currently working on testing the REST API and need to send some request in JSON format to a server which I am testing through JMeter.So, how can I send the encrypted request by AES encryption instead of the plain text transmission using JMeter? I have the key and IV

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box JMeter can use [__digest()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) function to return encrypted value using algorithms:

- MD2
- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-224
- SHA-256
- SHA-384
- SHA-512

But there are no [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) support by default. To be able work with it follow this steps:

1. Check this question to find out how to deal with AES in Java: [Java aes encrypt decrypt example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example)
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to JMeter Test Plan, choose `Java Beanshell Engine` in it's `Language` option and use The Java Power to crypt your JSON.
3. Check more information about [advanced usage of BeanShell](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/testing-complex-logic-with-jmeter-beanshell/)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @indikakariyawasam If this solve your question, you may accept this answer and upvote it, as correct.
Thank you!